# Monotouch C# play many sounds simultaneously with volume control

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, avaudioplayer, system-sounds

I'm making a War Game for iOS using Monotouch and C#.  I'm running into some problem with the audio sound effects.

**Here's what I require**:  The ability to play many sound effects simultaneously (possibly up to 10-20 at once) and the ability to adjust volume (for example, if the user zooms in on the battlefield the gun shot volume gets louder).

**Here are my problems:**

With AVAudioPlayer, I can adjust volume but I can only play 1 sound per thread.  So if I want to play multiple sounds I have to have dozens and dozens of threads going just incase they overlap...  This is a war game, picture 20 soldiers on the battlefield.  Each soldier would have a "sound thread" to play gun fire sounds when they shoot because It is possible that every soldier could just happen to fire at the same exact time.  I don't have a problem with making lots of threads, but my game already has dozens of threads running all the time and adding dozens more could get me into trouble... right?  So I'd rather not go this road of adding dozens of more threads unless i have too...

With SystemSound, I can play as many sounds as I want in the same thread, but I can't adjust the volume.... So my work around here is, for every sound effect i have - save it like 4 times at 4 different volumes.  That is a big pain... Any way to adjust volume with SystemSounds??

Both of these answer some of my requirements, but neither seems to be a seamless fit.  Should I just go the AVAudioPlayer multi-threading nightmare road?  Or the SystemSound multi-file-with-different-volume-levels nightmare road?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "but my game already has dozens of threads running all the time " - really? Why is that?

Comment: Each soldier has two threads.  A "Move" thread that is responsible for moving the soldier around the battlefield.  And an "Engage" thread that is responsible for the soldier "Scanning", "Targeting", "Shooting", "Reloading" etc... They are separate threads so that each soldier can operate independently from the next.  So if the battlefield has 20 soldiers on it, that's 40 threads right there...  50 soldiers, 100 threads.  Now I'm looking at possibly adding audio threads for each soldier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the solution to my problem.  AVAudioPlayer IS capable of playiing multiple sounds at once but only with certain file formats... The details are available in this link.  The reason why I couldn't play my sound effects simultaneously was because the file format was compressed and the iphone only has 1 hardware decompressor.

http://brainwashinc.wordpress.com/2009/08/14/iphone-playing-2-sounds-at-once/